# why every parallel promise obtains same value(res is always 5 async not working)?

Tags: javascript, promise

this launches a promise with different times of resolving

those ones are in parallel but the fact of counter

being a refrence that is at its final value when async
works finally does me obtain the same value for res (always 5)
any workaround this ?

```
//to test dynamics additions based on functions returning
//promises as iterators
var moitabla = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
moitabla.setAttribute("id", "mit");
var moitexto = document.createTextNode("to add");
var mirow = document.createElement("tr");
var mitd = document.createElement("td");
mirow.appendChild(mitd);
mitd.appendChild(moitexto);
moitabla.appendChild(mirow);
//here it comes
function* gen() {
    let i = 0;
    for (/*let must be here  or do closure for it */i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        yield(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                resolve(i);
            }, i * 1000);//end timeout
         }/*end function anonymous*/ 
        )//end new promise
       ); //end promise parse envelper
    }; //endfor
}; //end gen
var it = gen();
var bar;
while (!(bar = it.next()).done) {
    bar.value.then(function(res) {
        console.log("done!! " + res);
    });
    //always done!! 5 no individual value
};
```

Comment: If you post code please use indent, because it's hard to read.

Comment: Maybe let bar instead of var bar?

Comment: `for (let i = 0;` ...

Comment: The problem is that you're create function inside for loop and i is always 5 when for loop finish after timer becasue your not creating new scope for i because it's outside for.

Comment: solved thx Jonas W.trying now with let bar